# Dropbox API for Android NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk, dropbox, dropbox-api

How would I go about using the Dropbox API directly from the android NDK (not java, but c/c++)?

Comment: Go to DropBox official site and search for C/C++ API. If you're lucky enough, there will have API for C/C++.

Answer (score 0):

There's no standard HTTP library in C++, so there's no official Dropbox API for C/C++. You'd be better off linking to Java. Or implementing OAuth and Dropbox REST calls by hand over an HTTP library of your choice. It's quite doable, if time consuming.

Since a part of implementing Dropbox by hand is popping up some logon UI, calling back into the Java world would be all but necessary.

Comment: I'm using ANativeActivity so that would mean calling java from native code. I've look at it for hours and it seems so cryptic. Is there a good example / tutorial somewhere for that?

Comment: Read up on JNI. The key objects on the native side are JavaVM and JNIEnv, both are available to the native activity. You retrieve a Java class object pointer, find methods, call them and so forth.